# Qt Visual Studio Add-In Problems

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2005, build-automation, add-in

I am using Qt 4.6.2 with the latest version of the Visual Studio Add-In(1.1.5) with Visual Studio 2005 Professional.

I am finding that whenever I restart Visual Studio or switch build targets(I am building Win32 & x64, Debug/Release builds) all of my moc, uic & rcc files will be regenerated even when the .h/.ui/.qrc files have not been changed.

Any ideas on how to fix this? It is causing a significant increase in build times.

Zac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, strange, I have checked with my settings, and don't find the same symptoms after switching Debug-Release. I used:

- Visual Studio Add-In(1.1.5) - made update from 1.1.4
- Visual Studio 2008 Pro

Here is my **Qt Options** dialog:

[image]

I'm building only Win32 target. Also you need to check MSVC compiler settings, for some rebuild options. Try default settings to apply.

Hope this information help.

Comment: I find that only sometimes when I swap between Debug & Release will it rerun moc/uic/rcc, not everytime, but it will happen every time I switch between Win32 & x64 Builds. My settings look pretty close to that except for the Moc Directory, is there a particular reason you have a separate Moc directory for Debug/Release? 

My Settings
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5e5fd314ca.jpg

Comment: I used default settings of the VS Add-in 1.1.5 and on my system  Debug/Release directories have the same content, I mean have the same file names (but differs only by the size). You could try to set `UicDirectory`, `RccDirectory` and `MocDirectory` the same value - `.\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)` and try to build your solution...

Comment: I'm still have lots of issues on various Qt projects where Visual Studio will want to keep running the UIC/Moc/Rcc steps on every build. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Zac Shenker Did you already checked new versions of VS (2010), Qt (4.7.0) and Qt Add-in (1.1.6)?